# Javascript use the replace matched substring in a array key

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace words in a sentence to emoticons. These emoticons are stored as followed:

```
Var emotesurl = {Emotename: 'URL'};
```

option1 is my sentence i want replaced
emoteregex is my regexp

what i have tried:

```
var option1 = 'I am cool DatSheffy';
var emoteregex = new RegExp("(Volcania|DatSheffy)","g");
var emotesurl = {DatSheffy:"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-bf13a0595ecf649c-24x30.png"};
option1.replace(emoteregex, emotesurl['DatSheffy']);   This returns url! YAY
option1.replace(emoteregex, "$&");   This returns DatSheffy
```

so what i thought would be possible is something like this:

```
option1.replace(emoteregex, emotesurl['$&']);
```

Which apparently doesnt work in javascript since it returns undefined. I am kinda clueless how to solve this issue.

So the end goal for this script part would be replace the word DatSheffy or any other from the regexp to the URL of the image of that specific emoticon. Where the Keyname in the array is the same as the matched regex.

Comment: might be worth posting the whole things are the part missed out make it hard to see whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you want the callback implementation of replace:

```js
var emotesurl = {'brown': 'URL', 'xxx': 'foo'}; 

var option1 = "how now [brown] cow [xxx] [z]";
    
option1 = option1.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/gi, function(a, b) {
    // a is '[brown]' b is 'brown' - return emotesurl value or current as default
    return emotesurl[b] || a;
});

alert(option1);
```